# libGDX Example Project in Eclipse Getting Error 87

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I was trying out the sample project using libGDX(a clone of Flappy Bird) in Eclipse. This is the link to the tutorial - http://www.kilobolt.com/day-2-setting-up-libgdx.html.

In the step 18(please visit the link), when I clicked the "Run as Java Application", I am getting error alert box with message "LoadLibrary failed with error 87:The parameter is incorect". What could be the reason?

Comment: Are you trying to start right version of application. Like, I have main version, where the code is, desktop, android and some other like ios. So I can't run main one, but only desktop and android. (Main one is not runnable and for ios I miss some libraries.)
So, I'm starting by selecting desktop project and pressing F11 shortcut.

Comment: Yes. I am trying to run the desktop version. I did what they said which was "Right click and Run the DesktopLauncher class (bottom left)".

Comment: I started by following this bucket example: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-simple-game
and everything went smooth..

Comment: sorry but I would love to know the reason behind the error.

Comment: If you are using the latest LibGDX, then I would use Android Studio instead. The Gradle project support is more seamless.

Comment: @Balu Ramachandran in the step 12 try to use import to gradel download the plugin, if you have not add Gradel http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok even though i didn't understand the reason, just got the solution from here http://aerotekit.com/win8-1-loadlibrary-failed-error-87-parameter-incorrect. This is an issue with windows 8.1 (my assumption) and it can be solved by editing the registry. Copy-pasting the solution below:

1. Copy this code into a text file:

   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0000]
   "OpenGLVendorName"=hex(7):61,00,74,00,69,00,6f,00,36,00,61,00,78,00,78,00,2e,\
   00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00,61,00,74,00,69,00,6f,00,36,00,61,00,78,00,78,00,\
   2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00,00,00
2. Now save the file and change the extension from .txt to .reg.  If you are unable to edit the extension you may have to go into your folder options and make the extensions viewable.Note:  The next step has you edit a registry entry. I recommend that you make a registry backup before proceeding.  While this is unlikely to cause any issues, it is better to be safe than sorry.
3. After you have the .reg file on your desktop just double click it and it will run.
4. Restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I was trying an example from book. I changed the jdk used in eclipse from 64 bit to 32 bit and this error was gone.